# one sub-domain name for multiple services

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx proxy server and i don't want to use another sub-domain.

**is it possible to redirect one domain name to multiple servers.**

eg: my register domain name: **user.example.com**
and my app servers are : **192.168.0.1:7000** and **192.168.0.2:8000**
i and looking to do is when i hit  **user.example.com** redirects to 192.168.0.1:7000 and   when i hit **user.example.com/1** this will redirect to 192.168.0.2:8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a configuration might be implemented using NGINX as reverse proxy, it is described very well in official documentation, e.g. in "NGINX reverse proxy" [guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). Basically it is just

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass 192.168.0.1:7000;
}

location /another/path/ {
    proxy_pass 192.168.0.2:8000;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but what about the url, as i said i have one subdomain and want to access my both servers from globally

Comment: That's exactly what I'm telling about: if NGINX server was configured to listen on IP address, corresponding to the given subdomain (i.e. **user.example.com** in the question), then requests to **user.example.com/some/path/** would be proxied to **192.168.0.1:7000**, and requests to **user.example.com/another/path/** -  to **192.168.0.2:8000**

Comment: ok. i tried but not succeed. eg:one port 7000 tomcat is running and port 8000 kibana4 is running. and here i dont have any app placed in any location. So in this case how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "and here i dont have any app placed in any location"?

Comment: That means like app server where application is running on specific location.

Comment: ok so thanks here i am able to achive it by specifying location based configuration. In case of kibana i have to place the path of application followed by port number. 
eg: proxy_pass 192.168.0.2:8000/applocation;